# How do I build an Alexa skill for only my device?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

This may be an extremely basic question, but I am not able to find the answer. Even if you can point me in the direction of documentation, I'd be grateful.

I have set up [AlexaPi](https://github.com/alexa-pi/AlexaPi/wiki) on a Raspberry Pi and am trying to code a bunch of skills for local use (a bit like the example [here](https://www.hackster.io/nishit-patel/controlling-raspberry-pi-using-alexa-33715b) though not precisely that).

What I am not able to understand is how I ensure that my skill does not become "public" and end up being used by accident by thousands of people. This is particularly the case because some of the skills are interactions for my kids.  The Alexa documentation doesn't seem to clearly state how one limits the devices on which a skill is used.  It talks of "private skills" but these are only for Alexa for Business users.

Am I missing something clearly elementary?

Comment: If you don't want the public to use don't publish it. keep it in dev skills. The only problem of this is you need to pair the Alexa with the same account where you created the skills.

Comment: Please make this an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 3):

You skill is never public until you publish it. Then it goes to a certification queue and, if approved, it will be live. Your skill is by default only visible to devices that have been configured with the account that you used to develop the skill at developer.amazon.com/alexa
You can safely use your skill privately in devices configured with that account and the sill will never be public (until you explicitly go to the Distribution tab and publish it)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the public to use don't publish it. keep it in dev skills. The only problem of this is you need to pair the Alexa with the same account where you created the skills